# Customize map output in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

As I have 4 key/value in map , I'm trying to store two keys in string format and rest two in an array but it's not taking array's multiple value.

right now what output I'm getting :

```
{ url: 'account/43',    
  status: '200',    
  headers: [ '\'content-type\' = \'application/json\'' ],    
  body: [ '{ "name": "Fatma Zaman" }' ]}
```

Expected output:

```
{ url: 'account/43',
  status: '200' ,
  headers: 
     [ 'content-type = application/json',  
       'content-type = application/text' ], 
  body: [ '{ name: Fatma Zaman }' ] }
```

below are the code which is returning either multiple headers value but all keys are in array format or url/status in string & headers/body in array.

```
 function processFile(content) {

    content.forEach(function(node) {

        if (node.startsWith("//")) {

            key = node.substring(2, node.length-2).toLowerCase().trim()

            return

        } else {

            value = node

        }       

        if (key in map) {

            map[key].push(value)

        } else {

            map[key]= [value]

        }

        map[key] = ["headers", "body"].includes(key)? [value] : value

     })

    return map

  }
```

if I add below code , it's giving me multiple value but not url/body not in string

```
        if (key in map) { 

      map[key].push(value) 

  } else { 

      map[key]= [value] 
  }
```

In short , I'm not able to achieve both at the same time. like multiple header value with url/status in string format. Any help and suggestion would be appreciate it

Here is the full code

```
const fs = require("fs")

const path = require("path")

let key

let value

let filePath

function parseFile(filePath) {

    filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../resources/FileData1.txt")

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {

        if (err) throw err

        content = data.toString().split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g).map(function(line) {

            return line.trim()

        }).filter(Boolean)

        console.log(processFile(content))

    })

}

function processFile(content) {

    content.forEach(function(node) {

        if (node.startsWith("//")) {

            key = node.substring(2, node.length-2).toLowerCase().trim()

            return

        } else {

            value = node

        }

        if  (key in map) {

            map[key].push(value)

        } else {

            map[key] = value

        }

        // map[key] = ["headers", "body"].includes(key)? [value] : value



    })

    return map

}

parseFile(filePath)

module.exports = {parseFile, processFile}
```

And input are in below format:

```
//Status//

200


//HEADERS//

content-type = application/json


//BODY//

{ name: Fatma Zaman }


//URL//

account/43


//HEADERS//

content-type = application/text
```

Comment: I don't see a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in your code. What you have a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: I haven't post the full code , now updated the code above. hopefully this will give more insight what actually i'm trying here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below code:

```
function processFile(content) {
let map ={};
content.forEach(function(node) {

    if (node.startsWith("//")) {

        key = node.substring(2, node.length-2).toLowerCase().trim()

        return

    } else {

        value = node

    }       

    if (["headers", "body"].includes(key)) {
        if(map[key]){
            map[key].push(value);
        }else{
            map[key] = [value]
        }
    } else {
        map[key]= value
    }
 })

return map 
}
```

This should work now, I have tested with the input. Kindly check and confirm :)

Comment: I'm getting below error with above solution:

ERROR

map[key].push(value)

                     ^

 

TypeError: map[key].push is not a function

Comment: Try now I have declared map variable

Comment: Oh I already have map variable declared globally , even if tried declaring variable inside function unfortunately the error is still same :-(

Comment: Please check now, I have made some change to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure what you want, but i think this code will help you:

```js
var yourObj = {
    url: 'account/43',
    status: '200',
    headers: ['\'content-type\' = \'application/json\''],
    body: ['{ "name": "Fatma Zaman" }']
};

console.log('Your obj:');
console.log(yourObj);

console.log('formatted:');
console.log(format(yourObj));


function format(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] != 'object') {
            obj[prop] = obj[prop].replace(/"|'/g, '');
        } else {
            obj[prop] = format(obj[prop]);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: your solution does make sense but unfortunately It's not taking multiple value of headers :-(

Comment: You edit your input and output, i will try to fix it, my english is bad so i don't sure i understand you.